# How to get ABC parameters from quadratic equation?

Tags: c, string, get, equation

I want to build a function which gets equation (string) like `ax^2+bx+c=0`(ex: `"3x^2+8=0"`) and get `a`,`b`,`c` parameters.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 25

void getABC(char str[]);
int a=0, b=0, c=0;

int main(void)
{
    char equation[STR_LEN]={0};

    printf("Enter an equation:\n");
    fgets(equation, STR_LEN, stdin);
    equation[strcspn(equation, "\n")]=0;

    getABC(equation);

    return 0;
}

void getABC(char str[])
{
    // how to get a, b and c?
}
```

Comment: `sscanf` would be of use here.

Comment: Please answer as selected , if it solved your query.

Comment: In your question the example input is `3x^2+8=0` With no ax^2 + bx + c , with no b , is it correct , or you have by mistake wrote that?

Comment: In your question the example input is 3x^2+8=0 With no ax^2 + bx + c , with no b , is it correct , or you have by mistake wrote that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Do this instead

```
   int a ;
   int b ;
   int c ;

   printf("Enter Equation : ");
   scanf("%dx^2+%dx+%d" , &a , &b , &c);
   printf("%d %d %d" , a ,b , c);
```

For Example If you enter `3x^2+4x+10` , then `3` will be stored in `a` , it will ignore `x^2` and `+` and then store `4` in `b` and then it will ignore `x` and `+` and store `10` in `c`.